# Они стали искать, что же осталось от их чувств среди осколков

Tags: синтаксис

Не могли бы вы помочь мне определить функцию ***что***:

> Они стали искать, ***что*** же осталось от их чувств среди осколков.

Сначала я думала, это союз, который вводит дополнительное предложение, но сейчас сомневаюсь может вопросительное слово "что"? Это на самом деле дополнительное предложение?

Comment: Предложение кажется незавершенным или нелогичным.  Они стали искать, что же осталось от их чувств среди осколков (чего?). Если это осколки их чувств, то эти осколки и есть то, что осталось от их чувств.

Answer (score 4):

**Они стали искать, что же осталось от их чувств среди осколков.**

**Слово ЧТО не союз, а союзное слово**, в придаточном предложении оно является подлежащим. (Союзы ― это не члены предложения).

Это предложение имеет структуру, близкую к двум типам СПП (изъяснительное и дополнительное)

1) Сравнить: **Они стали искать то, что еще осталось от их чувств.**

Тип придаточного предложения: **местоименно-определительное** (или местоименно-соотносительное), местоименная связь осуществляется по схеме ***то ― что***.

Местоимение ***то***  (коррелят/соотносительное слово/указательное слово)  является **дополнением** в главном предложении, поэтому придаточное, раскрывающее его содержание, можно назвать **дополнительным.**

2) **Они стали думать, что же осталось от их чувств.**

Тип придаточного предложения: **изъяснительное**.

Местоимение ***то*** отсутствует, ***что*** ― союзное слово, опорное слово ***думать*** со значением мысли, частица ЖЕ усиливает вопросительный характер местоимения ***что***.

**Союзное слово  используется как средство связи** в том случае, если в начале придаточного стоит местоимение (что, где, когда и др.).

**Примечание**

В **изъяснительных** предложения местоимение ***что*** часто является союзом, например: **Они подумали, что ничего не осталось от их чувств.**

Что ― союз, ничего ― подлежащее.